# Angular js click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angularjs.  I want to navigate to other controller (detailscontroller)  and the detail.html page by clicking the link from (Homecontroller). But while navigate to the detailscontroller i should pass the parameter value from Homecontroller. Below is my screenshot

[image]

By clicking delete it should navigate to the detailscontroller controller and trigger the below function

**detailsController**

```
myApp.controller("detailsController", function ($scope, $http,GENERAL_CONFIG,$filter) {

    $scope.getdetailsbyspider = function(spider){
        console.log(spider)

    }


});
```

Where as the `spider`  should be from the Homecontroller ( the click value)

How can i do this ? Can anyone help me ?

**UPDATE: My router**

```
.when("/details", { templateUrl: 'Details.html', controller: 'detailsController' })
```

**Home.html**

```
<tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="row in finished">
                   <td> {{row.project}} </td>
                <td> <a href="#details" ng-click="getdetailsbyspider(row)"> {{row.spider}}</a></td>
```

to get the above table

**Update** 
When i click the Spider name page should be navigate to the details.html with the spider name clicked.

In this example when i click on the **delete** it should navigate to the details.html and execute the getdetailsbyspider function in the detailscontroller with the spider name as delete

Thanks,

Comment: Are you use ngRoute? If use it, you can replace `console.log` with `$location.path(/YourControllerPath)`

Comment: i will do like dddd1919 says and add the parameter spide to the url

Comment: .when("/details", { templateUrl: 'Details.html', controller: 'detailsController' })   Here is my route info

Comment: please post more of your code

Comment: Hi @DonJuwe i have added the details

Comment: I have updated my post. Can you please help me

Comment: you didn't tell us where the problem is. does the redirect work? is the template and the controller being loaded?

Comment: @DonJuwe the redirection is working fine. But the getdetailsbyspider  is not able to access. Getting problem in the controller level i hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will do like dddd1919 says and add the parameter spide to the url
in homecontroller :

```
       myApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $http,GENERAL_CONFIG,$filter) {
         $scope.callGetDetail = function(spider){
            console.log("callGetDetail");
            $location.path("/YourDomaine/#/details/getdetailsbyspider="+spider);
        }
     });
```

in the view where you want to make the call, home.html

```
          <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="row in finished">
               <td> {{row.project}} </td>
            <td> <a href="#details" ng-click="callGetDetail(row)"> 
             {{row.spider}}</a>
            </td>
```

in the router

```
    when('/details/:params', {
        templateUrl: 'Details.html',
        controller: 'detailsController'
     }).
```

in the detailsController:

```
     myApp.controller("detailsController", function ($scope, $http, GENERAL_CONFIG, $filter,$routeParams) {
        $scope.getdetailsbyspider = function(spider){
            console.log("getdetailsbyspider "+ spider)
        }

        function myUrlToArray(url) {
           var paramsFormatted = {};
           var paramstmp = decodeURI(url).split("&");
           for (var index = 0; index < paramstmp.length; ++index) {
              var tmp = paramstmp[index].split("=");
              paramsFormatted[ tmp[0] ] = tmp[1];
           }
           return paramsFormatted;
        }
       var params =  myUrlToArray($routeParams.params)
       if(params.getdetailsbyspider != null ){
                  $scope.getdetailsbyspider(params.getdetailsbyspider);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am new to angular. Where to add this  $location.path("/YourDomaine/#/details/getdetailsbyspider="+spider)

Comment: It is being called twice :(

Comment: what is been called twice ? what is displayed in the consol ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> the redirection is working fine. But the getdetailsbyspider is not
>   able to access. Getting problem in the controller level i hope

the problem will be that the controller function

```
$scope.getdetailsbyspider = function(spider){
    console.log(spider)
}
```

is not part of the controller you are currently in when you trigger it. That means you call the function by clicking on a link in your `home.html` but the `detailsController` is not assigned to that view.

To prove that just copy the function into your `HomeController` (or whatever its name is) and you will see the logging will work.